# Trying to send email as per date and time mentioned

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to create a spreadsheet automation creating google script which sends email to a specific person getting values from Spreadsheet. I have a column which mentions which mentions schedule date and time. I wanted to send email as per scheduled date, does anyone have any idea how I can mentions in my function

```
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
+       Schedule       +    Email      +    Subject  +    Message  +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
+ 04/22/2015 18:00:00  + abc@abc.com   +      Hi     +      Hi     +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
+ 04/25/2015 14:00:00  + def@gmail.com +      Hi     +      Hi     +
+----------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+

function sendEmails() {
for (k = programFirstRow; k < totalProgramRows + 1; k++)
  {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var sendDate = SendSheet.getRange("A"+k).getValues();
  var emailAddress = SendSheet.getRange("B"+k).getValues();
  var Subject = SendSheet.getRange("C"+k).getValues();
  var message = SendSheet.getRange("D"+k).getValues();
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

Comment: A few notes on your code unrelated to this question: 

 Avoid calling the spreadsheet service inside of a loop, this is a very slow process and can easily bog down your script. Similarly, you can get the entire values range of the sheet with `mySheet.getDataRange().getValues()` outside of a loop and then manipulate that to retrieve the data you need. More info: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically setup Installable Triggers: [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically)

Specifically you can programmatically install a time based trigger: [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timebased)

Example:

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myEmailFunction')
.timeBased()
.atDate(myDateObject)
.create();
```

You can iterate through your sheet and create time based triggers for each email. However, these only have a time granularity of 15 minutes. So it will execute up to 15 before or 15 minutes after the specified trigger time.

I won't write a full example for you, since figuring it out is part of the learning process. The linked documentation is more than enough to get you started.

Comment: You didn't get it I am date and time is already specified in my spreadsheet. The only thing to detect the time on the date which it is needed to send. I don't want to create time based trigger.

Comment: @Love0915 Do you not want to automatically send the emails at the times specified in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes. That is want I am trying and wanted to do.

Comment: @Love0915 If that is your goal, then this will work. If you want to send an email based on the time on the sheet, this is how you would do it.